# Where to find the path and the name of the tpl file in source code in 4.7.16

Tags: drupal, templates

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.16 with Drupal 7.

In the previous versions, the invoice tpl file can be found by viewing the page source html in the browser. It's in a comment line and it is something like

```
<!-- xxx.tpl file invoked ... -->
```

But I couldn't find these comment lines when viewing source in CiviCRM 4.7.16.

How do I find the invoked template in 4.7?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a description of what you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: What is the url you are looking at the source for? You get only the first .tpl invoked, and it may include others.

Answer (score 4):

In current 4.7 you need to enable debugging for the tpl to be shown in the source.  Go to `Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling` then select `Enable Debugging` and save.  Remember to disable it when done.